# Using "unsigned long long" as iteration-range in for-loop using OpenMP

Tags: for-loop, g++, iteration, openmp, long-integer

If I do this it works fine:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++) { ... }
```

this still works fine

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <= 200; i++) { ... }
```

but this isnt working

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <= LLONG_MAX; i++) { ... }
```

-> compiler error: invalid controlling predicate

LLONG_MAX is coming from

```
#include <limits.h>
```

g++ --version -> g++ (tdm64-1) 5.1.0

it is said that openmp 3.0 can handle unsigned integer - types.

I searched alot for this issue, without success. They all use int as iteration-variable.
Someone knows a solution?

Comment: What is LLONG_MAX on your platform? That's the problem here, not OpenMP type issues.

Comment: cout << LLONG_MAX << endl; -> 9223372036854775807, I also tried with the ULLONG_MAX value 18...ULL, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed the program to:

```
unsigned long long n = ULLONG_MAX;
#pragma omp parallel for
for (unsigned long long i = 1; i < n; i++) { ... }
```

it seems to work now. Thank you Jeff for the hint.

i tried before with:

```
for (auto i = 1; i < n; i++) { ... }
```

-> no error, but loop didnt produce an output, very strange.

Comment: This feels like a GCC bug. Have you tried with Clang (latest w/ OpenMP), Intel, etc?

Comment: dont know what you mean: i have an amd-cpu and use g++ ... -fopenmp, cant test it on intel

Comment: Intel compiler supports AMD because they are both x86.